# Log growth formula - can I model cumulative revenue which appears logarithmic using a formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Exponential growth formula, e.g. compound interest looks something like this:

$$A(t)=A^{kt}$$

The amount after time period t is the initial amount (Principal) $A$ to the power of $k$ * the number of time periods.

Logs and exponents are related. Given that, I'd like to know if I can wrangle the above formula to fit my use case. I'm especially interested in $k$, which seems to determine the shape of the growth curve.

We have an app that generates revenue, here's a scaled and disguised example of how it appears visually:

[image]

For a collection of cohorts (dates), if I plot the length of time since the app has been installed against cumulative revenue, the curve looks logarithmic. Here's the same data against `log(Tenure)`:

[image]

Not perfectly linear but for the sake of this post can we pretend it is - I have a logarithmic relationship between cumulative revenue and tenure that I'd like to use to try to predict future cumulative revenue of new cohorts.

I have an initial amount. For each cohort, group of customers that install the app on a given day, after 3 weeks I'd like to look at their total revenue as an 'initial value' and then use a formula to estimate what their cumulative revenue might be after 90, 180, n days of tenure.

I searched for 'log growth formula' but didn't find anything as well defined as the exponential growth formula. Maybe I can modify it, it's just not clicking.

With an initial amount $A$ after 3 weeks of install for a given cohort and with historical data showing me logarithmic growth of the amount against tenure, is there a function I can write? Some equivalent of $k$ in the exponential growth formula that would describe the shape of the log growth where I could then plug in my initial amount, $k$ and then calculate my estimate for e.g. 90 days of tenure?

Comment: You may be interested in knowing that the typical form of the exponential growth/decay equation looks like $$A(t)=Ae^{kt}$$ instead.

Comment: Hi @AndrewChin OK thanks!